# Bash isolate result

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I start in bash and I would like to realize a script that checks the data on the command ibstat
Ibstat returns this for example:

```
command ibstat
Ibstat returns this for example:

# ibstat
CA 'mlx4_0'
        CA type: MT25418
        Number of ports: 2
        Firmware version: 2.3.0
        Hardware version: a0
        Node GUID: 0x0002c9030002fb04
        System image GUID: 0x0002c9030002fb07
        Port 1:
                State: Active
                Physical state: LinkUp
                Rate: 20
                Base lid: 2
                LMC: 0
                SM lid: 1
                Capability mask: 0x02510868
                Port GUID: 0x0002c9030002fb05
        Port 2:
                State: Down
                Physical state: Polling
                Rate: 10
                Base lid: 0
                LMC: 0
                SM lid: 0
                Capability mask: 0x02510868
                Port GUID: 0x0002c9030002fb06
```

I would like for each port to check that Physical state: is equal to LinkUp otherwise I return an error.
I arrive with grep and awq to isolate the 1st Physical state, but how do we make a kind of for loop to check each "node" port?

this is my actual code:

```
ibstat | grep "Physical state" | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

i want to separate Port number (in for or while ?)

For output result i want a error message like :
"Error port 2 is not linkup"

Comment: `grep` will give you all results, except you tell it not to. Show your code.

Comment: What is your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have edited my message

Comment: Perhaps something like `ibstat | grep -qP 'Physical state: (?!LinkUp)' && echo "Error!"`?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

As `awk` is no longer acceptable (!), here is a `bash` version:

```
ibstat | while IFS=':' read f1 f2; do
   # If first field is "Port", remember port in variable $p
   [[ $f1 =~ .*Port.* ]] && p="$f1"
   # If first field is "Physical state"
   if [[ "$f1" =~ "Physical state" ]]; then
      # Just carry on if second field is "LinkUp"
      [[ $f2 =~ "LinkUp" ]] && continue
      echo "ERROR: $p is not LinkUp ($f2)"
   fi
done
```

Obviously you would put in a script, called `CheckLink` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=':' read f1 f2; do
   # If first field is "Port", remember port in variable $p
   [[ $f1 =~ .*Port.* ]] && p="$f1"
   # If first field is "Physical state"
   if [[ "$f1" =~ "Physical state" ]]; then
      # Just carry on if second field is "LinkUp"
      [[ $f2 =~ "LinkUp" ]] && continue
      echo "ERROR: $p is not LinkUp ($f2)"
   fi
done
```

and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x CheckLink
```

and then run it with

```
ibstat | ./CheckLink
```

**Sample Output**

```
ERROR:         Port 2 is not LinkUp ( Polling)
```

---

**Original Answer**

How about this:

```
ibstat | awk -F: '$1~/Port [0-9]+/{p=$1} /Physical state:/ && ! /LinkUp/{print p,$2}'
```

**Sample Output**

```
Port 2  Polling
```

So, every time we see `Port` followed by a space and some digits, we remember the port in variable `p`. Every time we see `Physical state:` but not with `LinkUp` on the same line, we print the port number we saved and the second field on the line.

---

Or, if you want *quick, dirty and simple*, you could just grep all the Ports and all the Physical states:

```
ibstat | grep -E "Port \d+:|Physical state:"
```

**Sample Output**

```
    Port 1:
            Physical state: LinkUp
    Port 2:
            Physical state: Polling
```